# Erro de conexão ao realizar consulta

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados

Sou iniciante em programação e estou tentando fazer conexão com um banco de dados.
Mas ao clicar no button "Pesquisar" para navegar pelo banco de dados e exbir valores na minha tela, o seguinte erro é gerado através de uma messagebox que eu coloquei no Catch:

> ""An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\ (caminho do
>   arquivo do banco de dados). A database with the same name exists, or
>   specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.""

Segue abaixo o meu código para conectar e exibir valores:

```
namespace trenodb
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static string strDb = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\aRtHuRz\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\trenodb\\trenodb\\dbTrenodb.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pesquisar = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [Id] = " + txtID;
        SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(strDb);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(pesquisar, conexao);
        SqlDataReader DR;
        try
        {
            conexao.Open();
            DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (DR.Read())
            {
                txtID.Text = DR.GetValue(0).ToString();
                txtNome.Text = DR.GetValue(1).ToString();
                txtFone.Text = DR.GetValue(2).ToString();
                txtEndereço.Text = DR.GetValue(3).ToString();
                DR.Close();
            } cmd.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conexao.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: você já tentou configurar sua string de conexão de forma diferente, pelas propriedades do projeto ?

Comment: Não, como eu poderia fazer isso ?
Ela fica bloqueada para escrever, nas propriedades.

Comment: Você clica com o botão direito em cima do seu projeto -> propriedades -> Na tela que abrir, procure pela aba Settings, em seguida você cria um nome, escolha o tipo Connection String, depois clique na coluna Value, ela vai ti dar a opção de criar a conexão com seu banco de dados. Assim que você terminar, a string de conexão irá aparecer para você nessa mesma coluna. Você tem a opção de copiar e colocar no lugar da string que vc está usando atualmente ou utilizar essa string através das propriedades do projeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou fazer um passo a passo como fazer para gerar a string de conexão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procure pela aba settings.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Configure a string de conexão com o banco de dados desejado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

String de conexão configurada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora você pode copiar ela e utilizar no local onde você passa a sua atual, ou, utilizar pela propriedades do projeto.

Exemplo:

string strConexao = IntegraOpLogSerraPark.Properties.Settings.Default.stringConexão;

Se você perceber, a stringConexão que criamos no projeto está logo após a propriedade Default. Assim a string de conexão configurada é retornada.